# olap4j errors after update Microsoft Analysis Server

Tags: ssas, mdx, olap4j

I use olap4j 1.2.0 and olap4j-xmla 1.2.0 to request a Microsoft Analysis Server 11.0.5058.0 cube with MDX requests.
No problem at all.

Since a migration to Microsoft Analysis Server 14.0.249.14 (New cube, but same Cube) an error occurs:
`org.olap4j.OlapException: Internal error: hierarchy '[HierarchyName]' not found in cube 'CUBE'`

In debug mode I also observe when browsing the cube that the XmlaOlap4jDimensions objects do not contain hierarchies when they should.

The same queries work perfectly with Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

Thank you for your help.